# React Native CryptoJS giving empty value for AES-256-CBC decryption

Tags: reactjs, react-native, encryption, cryptojs

I'm using this https://github.com/imchintan/react-native-crypto-js package for React Native CryptoJS and I used this online tool https://www.javainuse.com/aesgenerator to generate this example data:

```
    const encryptedData = {
        cipher: "OuCmv1nXCzfy+529oeJU8g==",
        iv: "1234123412341234",
        key: "56785678567856785678567856785678"
    }
```

While encrypting the Mode selected is `CBC`, the Key Size is `256` bits, the output format is `base64` in react native this is how I'm decrypting it:

```
    let bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData.cipher, encryptedData.key);
    let originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    console.log("Text is: " + originalText);
```

But all I'm getting is `Text is:` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you provide a CryptoJS Cipher a 'key' that is actually a string, it treats it as a passphrase and uses password-based key derivation compatible with OpenSSL `enc` as specified [in the documentation](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input). You need to convert the key and iv to `WordArray`s much as shown [just above that](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#custom-key-and-iv), plus I can't find how to make the 'configurable' parsing work so I also parse explicitly as shown just below.

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("56785678567856785678567856785678")
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("1234123412341234")
var ctx = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("OuCmv1nXCzfy+529oeJU8g==")
var enc = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ciphertext:ctx})
console.log( CryptoJS.AES.decrypt (enc,key,{iv:iv}) .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8) )
->
Talha
```

Technically the result of `decrypt`, like `parse`, is a `WordArray`, so calling it `bytes` is somewhat misleading and confusing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. This works for this particular example, but what I didn't realize was that the base64 object that I'm getting after I hit an API when decrypted will give me a string that. I'll have to parse it as JSON data. As when the data is encrypted as JSON.stringify(data)

The developer gave me this gist as a reference of how he's encrypting the data https://gist.github.com/siwalikm/8311cf0a287b98ef67c73c1b03b47154

This is my first time working with AES so I'm not sure what goes where, but if possible can you update your answer to show how to handle this?

Comment: ^^ to add to the above I made some changes like I directly added `response.data` and add `KEY` and `IV` as strings I get this long `{"sigBytes": 26848, "words":...` gets printed in the log.

Comment: The result of `decrypt` is a WordArray, as I said, and if you output that _object_ you get the result you show; that's why you need to call `.toString(encoder)` to make it a string, as I showed. Once you have a string handling it as JSON is a completely separate problem that has nothing to do with AES, was not in your question, and I don't have the experience to help with, but I'm sure has been covered on Stack hundreds or thousands of times.

Comment: Got it! thank you. I think the encoder at my end is giving me `Malformed UTF-8 data` that means during encryption the backed guy has not properly encrypted it.

Comment: The CryptoJS code can be implemented much more compactly by passing the Base64 encoded ciphertext *directly* to `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()`, see https://jsfiddle.net/9o01Lmez/. The conversions `var ctx = ...` and `var enc = ...` are done under the hood and the corresponding lines can therefore be omitted.